# Android Oreo - GCM

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

Below code is referenced from google to support GCM,

```
        <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
        android:name="com.example.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
        android:name="com.example.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Query 1. As per google documentation, [Background execution limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html) make any impacts on above for Android Oreo? Or it would work as expected without making any code change?

Also, as google suggested below,

> If you're targeting Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher in your app development, use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). Otherwise, use the JobIntentService class instead of the IntentService to handle token refreshes.

Query 2. Based on above statement is Below approach correct ?

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {

 //start JobIntentService

} else {
 // start intent service
}
```

If YES, then who is the caller of enqueueWork?

**Note:** Due to some limitation, Can't move to FCM.

Answer (score 1):

No need to check versions. Just start the JobIntentService. If its below Oreo then it will work like a simple IntentService.

Comment: Sure , Thanks for your reply.